# Start Appium Server on bat file with version 1.6.4

Tags: batch-file, appium

With the previous version of Appium, I could start an appium server through command line in batch like this.

```
START node.exe node_modules\appium\bin\appium.js --port 4723
```

But now since the new release 1.0.0 (or 1.6.4) depends on how you calling it, There no node.exe anymore or appium.js either.

Can someone tell me where can I find these file ? or the "new" way of doing it ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: This is clearly an issue with your software, it's installation or path referencing and is therefore off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

With Appium 1.6.4, there are 2 ways of installing/using it -

1. We can do it the old fashioned way with Node. Installation happens via node with command  - `npm install -g appium`. Then you can run it the same way you mentioned in your post.
2. If we install it via Appium Desktop (v1.0.0), then we don't need Node and the server can be started using the Appium Desktop UI.

I have also used `appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723` in command prompt and it works fine. And if you want to look at Java code to start appium, you can check this out as well - [Start Appium server with Java](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/3-ways-to-start-appium-server-from-java/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use main.js in place of appium.js to start the appium, it is the change we need to incorporate from Appium 1.6.4